# Updating the storage variable

Tags: solidity

I am new in Solidity, please advise.

I have a code

```
    uint public bal = address(this).balance;
    
    function getBalance() public view returns (uint) {
            return address(this).balance;
    }
```

bal variable is 0 by default. I sent 10 Wei to the contract and when I check the bal again - it is still 0. I check the balance with getBalance() function and it shows
10 as expected. Why bal was not updated even it was stated as a global variable? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable `bal` is returning zero, because at the time of declaring this variable the contract balance was zero. This variable is stored in the state of the contract and it is not dynamically reading the **current** contract balance.

If for whatever reason you need `bal` variable to be up to date with the contract balance then on each `address(this).balance` call you will have to update `bal` value as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Miroslav. Initially, I thought that global variable has a link to a storage balance value and should be updated each time when something changing (it seems logical to me). Thank you one more time!

Comment: Great, if I cleared the picture for you please accept the answer so others having the same question can recognize the answer.